# Stop re-rendering existing components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component e.g. `<Test />`
I call this component in several times on my page, each time it is to change its image by changing the src to a random number (e.g. `/images/1.jpg`). This works not a problem, my issue is that when I render the new component it changes its random image but also re-renders all instances of that component that already exist on the page to change it's image again.

Is there a way I can only update the newest version of the component without re-rendering the existing?

```
class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    items: Array.from({ length: 5 })
  };

  fetchMoreData = () => {
      this.setState({
        items: this.state.items.concat(Array.from({ length: 5 }))
      });
  };

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <p>
            Infinite Scrolling Goats
            <span className="small-text">
              (Not Infinite Scrotes, sorry)
            </span>
          </p>
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          </header>
          <Toggle>
          <InfiniteScroll
            dataLength={this.state.items.length}
            next={this.fetchMoreData}
            hasMore={true}
            loader={<h4>Loading...</h4>}
          >
            {this.state.items.map((i, index) => (
            <Goat />
          ))}
          </InfiniteScroll>
          </Toggle>
      </div>
    );
  }
  }
```

is my app.js and is calls the following component

```
class Goat extends Component {

    render(){

        const arNames = [
            'Napoleon',
            'Albert',
            'Phil',
            'George',
            'Graham',
            'Bertie',
            'Dexter',
            'Frankie',
            'Tommy',
            'Kyle',
            'Jacko',
            'Freddy',
            'Jezza',
            'Stepho',
          ];

        var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        let randomName = arNames[Math.floor(Math.random()*arNames.length)];

        return(

            <div className="GoatItem" onScroll={this.handleScroll}>
                <img className="GoatImg" src={ "/images/goats/" + rand + ".jpg" }/>
                <div className="GoatContent">
                    <p>Name: {randomName}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Reference: https://lukes-code-infinitescroats.netlify.com

Comment: yes there is the way to do it , if you provide some source code here

Comment: A small code would help a lot figuring out your problem, i just think that whatever rerenders on your code must be called on the new component.

Comment: please post some code

Comment: In react whatever you write insde `render()` is re-rendered , whenever state changes, no matter what.

Comment: yes we can use life cycle method before that can you please share your code ?

Comment: Code has been added. Sorry, I was rushing and should have waited until I could provide more.

Answer (score 0):

From the implementation of `Goat` component, I can see that it is just a static component that does not change due to prop changes. Hence you can do this:

```
class Goat extends Component {
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps){
        return false;
    }

    render(){

        const arNames = [
            'Napoleon',
            'Albert',
            'Phil',
            'George',
            'Graham',
            'Bertie',
            'Dexter',
            'Frankie',
            'Tommy',
            'Kyle',
            'Jacko',
            'Freddy',
            'Jezza',
            'Stepho',
          ];

        var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        let randomName = arNames[Math.floor(Math.random()*arNames.length)];

        return(

            <div className="GoatItem" onScroll={this.handleScroll}>
                <img className="GoatImg" src={ "/images/goats/" + rand + ".jpg" }/>
                <div className="GoatContent">
                    <p>Name: {randomName}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Now if the component later accepts some props, such as say `image`, just replace `return false` with `return this.props.image === nextProps.image`. This will ensure, component will re-render only when `image` prop changes.

But I would advise against doing this optimization, as the DOM tree for this component is small. Hence even if the component re-renders, the virtual DOM diffing will be very fast. Verify the performance lag with dev tools before doing this.

Comment: Thanks you for you reply, in this early instance the `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps){
        return false;
    }` is all I seem to need!